# How can I replace a newline (in a plain text field) with a comma?

Tags: templating

I need to convert a new line in a plain multiline text field in Craft into a comma.

My text looks like:

```
1 Infinite Loop
Cupertino, CA
```

and I want to convert it to: `1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA`

I tried doing `{{ text|nl2br|replace({ '<br>', ', ' })|raw }}` but that didn't work.

Comment: I suspect nl2br was actually inserting <br/> or <br /> instead of <br>, so your replace wasn't matching anything.

This would probably do it: {{ text|nl2br|replace({ '<br>': ', ', '<br/>': ', ', '<br />': ', ' })|raw }}

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the best way to do this was to replace the newline character `\n`.

Final code:

```
{{ plainText|replace({ "\n" : ", "}) }}
```

Comment: Line endings are unfortunately a good bit more involved than just `"\n"` -- if you can't control the input, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way